# Swift: Resize/Scale UIBezierPath dynamically with parent view size

Tags: ios, swift, resize, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I am using `UIBezierPath` and `CAShapeLayer` to draw a line and adding it inside a view as a sublayer. Everything works fine, Now I have to resize 'Line' with its parent view with strictly keeping the proportion same of line with the view.

Here is the code of creating a line:

```
let line = UIBezierPath.arrow(from: startPoint, to: endPoint, tailWidth: 5, headWidth: 20, headLength: CGFloat(inputLength * 0.1))
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = line .cgPath
self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess you can scale the view that holds the path, like

```
let scaleWidth = toSize.width / fromSize.width
let scaleHeight = toSize.height / fromSize.height
path.apply(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleWidth, y: scaleHeight))
```

and use the scale factor to get a certain point of the path too